# emacs: slime-repl hang if using read() or read-line() function

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, clisp, slime

I am using Emacs 24.3.1 on Ubuntu 14.04, slime-20160402.549, GNU CLISP 2.4. Whenever i use read() or read-line() function in slime-repl, it will freeze after one or two input characters (e.g. "wa"),

```
    ; SLIME 2016-04-02
    CL-USER> (read)
    wa
```

Trying C-g it shows the error below:

```
    Debugger entered--Lisp error: (quit)
      accept-process-output(nil 0.01)
      #[0 "\306\307!\306\310!\211\302L\266\211\211\300L\266\311\312J\301@\313\314\315\316\317D\316\nD\316\fD\320\257E\257!\266\321\322\323 \322\262\322\262\324!\325=\204J  
      slime-eval((swank:simple-completions "wa" (quote "COMMON-LISP-USER")))
      slime-simple-completions("wa")
      ac-source-slime-simple-candidates()
      ac-candidates-1(((init . ac-slime-init) (candidates . ac-source-slime-simple-candidates) (candidate-face . ac-slime-menu-face) (selection-face . ac-slime-selection-face) (prefix . slime-symbol-start-pos) (symbol . "l") (document . ac-slime-documentation) (match . ac-source-slime-case-correcting-completions)))
      ac-candidates()
      ac-update(t)
      ac-show-menu()
      apply(ac-show-menu nil)
    ...
```

This problem does not happen in clisp REPL on command line.
Any helps?

Comment: Did you pressed `TAB` after the characters, or performed some other operation on Emacs? This could cause the problem. From the message it seems an elisp error (the emacs language), not a clisp error.

Comment: Perhaps you have some kind of automatic completions available (like a drop down list) and you get the hang when slime tries to find completions while the lisp is trying to read. I don't know if the problem might be to do with multi threading in clisp.